# Running Thunderbird Portable in Sandboxie

Tags: thunderbird, portable, sandboxie

I'm trying to run Thunderbird portable in Sandboxie but it doesn't work.
I'm getting an access denied error - any ideas if it's possible?

Comment: I just downloaded Thunderbird v3.1.2 portable from http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/thunderbird_portable and it seems to be working fine. Where are you getting the error? Did you run it in the Default Sandbox or Outside the Sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are probably not able to send/receive mail because the sandboxie might be boxing your thunder-bird's network access
- Another reason could be because Mozilla people might have blocked this portable version
- Some people are able to solve the problem by choosing "Auto-detect proxy" instead of having a "Direct Connection".
- You Will be able to run Thunder Bird in Oracle Virtual Machine which also functions similar  to a sandboxie